# Как записывать данные в файлы?

Tags: flutter

Пробую записать данные в файл (по пути: внутреннее хранилище/school) , но выходит ошибка, код:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
Future<String> get _externalPath async {
  final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

  return directory.path;
}
Future<File> get _dbExportFile async {
  final path = await _externalPath;
  return File('$path/school/db.cvs');
}
Future exportDB() async {
  final file = await _dbExportFile;
  return file.writeAsString('test');
}
```

Ошибка:

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getStorageDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider

Права в манифест добавил.
Если что, то это всё в режиме дебага

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполните эту команду и запустите этот код:

> flutter clean

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

static Future<Directory> get _getExternalStorageDirectory  async =>  await getExternalStorageDirectory();

uture<String> get _externalPath async {
  final directory = await _getExternalStorageDirectory;

  return directory.path;
}
Future<File> get _dbExportFile async {
  final path = await _externalPath;
  return File('$path/school/db.cvs');
}
Future exportDB() async {
  final file = await _dbExportFile;
  return file.writeAsString('test');
}
```

Если не поможет понизите версию плагина, возможно на данной версии есть баг.

[Issues на GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912#issuecomment-310499594)